# What are those line highlighted suppose to do

Tags: python, csv

I don't know what the lines commented below is suppose to do, can somebody help me out.

```py
df_scraped = pd.read_csv("labeled_tweets.csv")
df_public = pd.read_csv("public_data_labeled.csv")
    
# df_scraped.drop_duplicates(inplace = True)
# df_scraped.drop('id', axis = 'columns', inplace = True)     
# df_public.drop_duplicates(inplace = True)
```

[LINK TO ORIGINAL CODE](https://github.com/dhavalpotdar/detecting-offensive-language-in-tweets/blob/master/cyberbullying_v2.ipynb)

Comment: they drop duplicates and drop some columns , why won't you refer to the pandas documentations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those lines are data pre-processing lines (or data cleaning).

1. The first line removes duplicate rows from df_scraped dataframe.
2. The second line removes the 'id' column.
3. The third line duplicate rows from df_public dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

`df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)` will perform the removal of duplicate rows from the dataframe. The `inplace = True` parameter causes the change to be performed in the dataframe and does not bring a copy.

`.drop('id', axis = 'columns', inplace = True)` removes the 'id' column.

Pandas Documentation :

[.drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

[.drop](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)